# The span of any two vectors in a vector space is a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

My first assumption that this statement is true, but what if these vectors were parallel?

Which leads me to a second thought, I know that a line through the origin of R2 and R3 is a subspace, but does this hold true for Rn?

If so then I must assume that former is true.

thanks

Comment: If the vectors are parallel, there is no problem, you just get a smaller subspace, but it's still a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

If it is parallel you get a vector space which is a straight line

[image]

It looks like this.

---

Also , watch this, I took this screenshot from this :

https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors_and_spaces/linear_combinations/v/linear-combinations-and-span

Answer (score 0):

If two vectors are parallel ( i.e. linearly dependent ), then the span of $v_1,v_2$ is the span($v_1$) itself.

You are right, a line through the origin is a subspace in $R^n$

You can show easily that it satisfies the properties needed for a vector space i.e. closure, existence of identity and inverse etc.